# Reversing words in a string method

Tags: c#

I tried using recursion for this.

Here is the code

```
  public static string ReverseWords(string str)
  {
    var splitArr = str.Split(" ");
    if(splitArr.Length == 1)
      return splitArr[0];
    
    return splitArr[splitArr.Length - 1] + " " + ReverseWords(String.Join(" ", splitArr.Take(splitArr.Length - 1));
  }
```

Comment: Recursion will kill itself with a string of any size (think War and Peace). A one-liner will do it: `string.Join(' ', str.Split(' ').Reverse())`

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. It is generally better to provide the entire class or program rather than just a single function so that we can provide a better review because there is more context. This is barely enough code to get a review.

Comment: [edit] your question to add more details. Also since you're new around here, take a [tour] and read [ask]

Comment: @pacmaninbw Sorry, but I don't get why I would be needing to provide entire class or program?
when the whole Logic is inside the function. And function takes in the string of words as I tell in my quesiton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is horribly inefficient both in terms of storage and runtime:

1. As already mentioned in comments (though not spelled out) recursion has a memory overhead directly proportional to the number of iterations - which in you case is input size.

Remember - every function call takes up stack space, and a recursive call is the same as regular call!

2. You create extra temporaries by rejoining the string you just split for the recursive call and having a string concatenation on each iteration.

That's two new strings create in every step in addition to the split array!

3. Everything mentioned in step 2 takes processing time as well as memory.

You will not notice this overhead with any string you might type in a console for testing, but try reading and reversing a sizable text file, and the problem will become apparent.